# Causal Inference on test scores

Tags: r, causality, causalimpact

I administered a test and wanted to know if the exam scores were influenced by watching videos. The participants were randomly entered into 2 arms. I have one control arm that did not watch videos, and the second arm being the group that did watch videos. I administered a pretest, had them watch the videos, and then take a post-test to the groups, acquiring their scores. After tallying them, I combined the two scores into a data set of scores with the pre-test data first and the post-test data afterward. I ran causalimpact in R on the set. Here are the results that I got.

```
Posterior tail-area probability p:   0.0111
Posterior prob. of a causal effect:  98.89%
```

I wanted to know if I implemented causal impact appropriately given that I combined both the pretest and posttest data into one set and split based upon when the pre-test data ended and the post-test data started. I also wanted to know if my assumption of causality would make sense in this instance.

Comment: The causalimpact library seems like overkill for this design.  If I have understood correctly, you randomized participants *and then* measured pre-test and post-test scores?

Comment: Casual? I guess you mean *causal*? Care to correct?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yep, I will correct, sorry for that.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Yes, I do.

Comment: @user1449249 You definitely don't need causalimpact then.

Comment: That's a very popular typo on this site ! ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to causal inference, but this sounds like a straightforward application of linear models.

You're interested in computing

$$ Pr(\mbox{Score} \vert do(\mbox{Videos}) ) $$

By randomizing, you have severed any arrows in your dag from confounders to the treatment.  So it should be, in principle, as easy as performing a t-test between the group scores.

However, you might say...

> But Demetri, what if the subjects in the experimental group all happen to be poor test takers.  I need to adjust for pre-test score.

The randomization addresses this issue.  If pre-intervention ability lead you to select which subjects got the intervention, then that would be a different story.  In that case, you have classic fork confounding where pretest ability causes treatment and the outcome.  Conditioning on pre-test ability would be the right thing to do in that scenario, but is not needed in the one you describe.

Comment: A t-test would be fine, but an ANCOVA controlling for pre-test would make the test way more powerful and the estimate of the effect more precise even with randomization. One should always adjust for pre-treatment predictors of the outcome (including pre-tests scores) when estimating effects after randomized trials.

Comment: I will accept this answer as it demonstrates that I didn't need a method of statistical analysis I thought I did.  Thanks @DemtriPananos